# How can I use my local Emacs client as the $EDITOR for remote machines I access over TRAMP?

Tags: emacsclient, tramp

I often use TRAMP to manage several remote servers, both for editing files and running remote shells in `shell-mode`. However, this does not work when a command uses the `EDITOR` variable to edit a file, such as `crontab -e` especially because `shell-mode` is a "dumb" terminal that does not support running another editor inside of it.

Locally, I do this with an appropriate call to `emacsclient` which opens up a new buffer and makes life very easy. Unfortunately, this does not work from the remote machine.

I guess I could use `ed`. (Hah!)

How can I set up a remote `EDITOR` that would let me edit files with my local Emacs instance?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**[NOTE]** this answer was heavily edited to follow the updates of `with-editor` developments. Most comments likely won't make much sense anymore. There are  some new comments which *do* make sense.

---

[Magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) contains a library named `with-editor` available at https://github.com/magit/with-editor which allows you 
to use your local Emacs as an $EDITOR on remote machines over TRAMP.

Another alternative is https://github.com/habnabit/remote-emacsclient, but it seems more complicated & less generic.

The simplest way to install `with-editor` is through MELPA:

<kbd>M-x package-install with-editor</kbd>

Otherwise, just grab https://github.com/magit/with-editor/blob/master/with-editor.el somewhere to your load path and `require` it (it also depends on dash).

Then, simply start `shell`, `eshell` or `ansi-term` and do the following:

<kbd>M-x with-editor-export-editor</kbd>

It'll ask you which $EDITOR you are interested in, just press enter for the default `EDITOR` variable. Then inside the shell you can type `crontab -e` and edit your crontab within emacs. Press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to save the crontab or <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> to cancel editing.

If you want a more permanent setup:

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook  'with-editor-export-editor)
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook   'with-editor-export-editor)
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'with-editor-export-editor)
```

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>M-x with-editor-async-shell-command crontab -e RET</kbd> for quick commands.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this `with-editor` library relates to the question? Sounds useful

Comment: @Silex: Would I need to set the `$EDITOR` variable to something on the remote machine for this to work? Does it just hook into `emacsclient`?

Comment: But yeah, this looks like exactly what I want. I'll have to give it a try somehow—I assume it can be installed by itself, without the rest of the branch?

Comment: @Malabarba: as said in the original post, you can call `M-x async-shell-command crontab -e RET` over TRAMP and it just opens the crontab buffer for editing in your local emacs instance. You then save with `C-c C-c`

Comment: @TikhonJelvi: it certainly *will* be installable by itself, but for now it's just part of `git-modes`. I'm following this lib closely and it's just that its author (@tarsius) is busy with releasing magit, but eventually it'd be a package of its own. About $EDITOR, you don't need to set it to anything yourself, it's done when needed when you run whatever commands uses it. Magit uses this lib with $GIT_EDITOR.

Comment: @Silex: I'm still a bit confused about that last point. Do you mean `$EDITOR` is set when I run an *emacs* command that uses it? But what if I just run `crontab -e` from a shell buffer—how would `crontab` know what to call if not from `$EDITOR`?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: I gave more details [in this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17753/discussion-between-silex-and-tikhon-jelvis). (Also I updated the answer to give steps to try with-editor out).

Comment: Note this will stop working after sshing to a remote from within an existing `shell-mode`/`term-mode` buffer. This can be addressed with some additional configuration, see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5589/automatically-update-default-directory-when-pwd-changes-in-shell-mode-and-term-m. If you do get it to work, then please report your findings at https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1638.

Comment: Using `with-editor` for something like "`crontab -e`" works for me, but how do I start editing an arbitrary file from an `M-x shell`? I tried "`$EDITOR file.txt`", but get the error message "`"WITH-EDITOR:: 1: "WITH-EDITOR:: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`"

Comment: If I follow the directions in the post, and run `ansi-term` and then `M-x with-editor-export-editor` and then ssh (from this ansi-term session) on a different computer (hoping to use my local emacs as the EDITOR) and run `crontab -e`, I get `emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?`. In short it looks like nothing changed and my local machine is still trying to use its default editor. Is there something else to configure?

Comment: @Startec: this won't work. Use TRAMP instead and spawn a remote shell with `M-x shell`, there `with-editor` would work. See @tarsius comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I have a tiny script in my path on the remote host at `~/bin/ec`, shorthand for emacsclient.

```
#!/bin/bash

params=()
for p in "$@"; do
  if [ "$p" == "-n" ]; then
    params+=( "$p" )
  elif [ "${p:0:1}" == "+" ]; then
    params+=( "$p" )
  else
    params+=( "/ssh:z:"$(readlink -f $p) )
  fi
done
emacsclient --server-file=$HOME/.emacs.d/server/server "${params[@]}"
```

This script passes `-n` and `+` args unchanged to emacsclient, otherwise args are treated as files for your local Emacs to open. Each file is prefixed with the TRAMP protocol and host so Emacs knows how to open it. You might be able to change `ssh:` to a different TRAMP protocol if you prefer.

You must replace `z` with the hostname of your remote machine. This is used by local Emacs to connect via TRAMP. (You might be able to use `hostname` here for generality. I prefer to use tiny entries like `z` in my local `ssh_config` for brevity, and the remote has no idea I'm doing this. Try it!)

Usage:

- `ec file` in the remote shell opens file in local Emacs and waits
- `ec -n file` in the remote shell opens file in local Emacs and returns
- `export EDITOR=~/bin/ec` in remote `.bashrc` makes the magic happen

To ensure my `server` file is good I have this in my local `.emacs`, again using the tiny hostname `z`:

```
(setq server-use-tcp t
      server-port    9999)
(defun server-start-and-copy ()
  "Start server and copy server file to remote box."
  (interactive)
  (server-start)
  (copy-file "~/.emacs.d/server/server" "/z:.emacs.d/server/server" t)
  (chmod "/z:.emacs.d/server/server" (string-to-number "644" 8))
  )
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'server-start-and-copy)
```

Port 9999 is a RemoteForward. I put this in my local `~/.ssh/ssh_config` to automate the forwarding, plus the ControlMaster stuff for speed.

```
Host z
HostName dev.example.com
User dev
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/z.sock
RemoteForward 9999 localhost:9999
```

Finally, make sure TRAMP knows about your `ssh_config` if you use it:

```
(require 'tramp)
(tramp-set-completion-function "ssh"
  '((tramp-parse-sconfig "~/.ssh/config")))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I have not tried this.

You could get part of the way by having a function watch command output for a command to open the file using TRAMP. Security hole? Yes. Functional? Probably.

Use a `shell-mode` hook to add a hook to `after-change-hook` in `shell-mode`. This hook watches for a specific sequence. Example:

```
;; RemoteTRAMP token: <authentication token maybe?>
;; RemoteTRAMP edit: /path/to/my/file
```

It then uses `tramp-find-file` to open the file. This is relatively secure because the ONLY THING that the remote can do is trigger a `tramp-find-file`. A confirmation first would be good but optional.

When editing is finished, another hook can trigger the exit of the dummy program (eg by sending `C-c`).

The worst case (for security) is that they find a way to run arbitrary code. If you have buffer-variables set to always evaluate, a malicious attacker could overwrite important settings without your knowledge. They could also launch a denial of service attack by causing many buffers to open. Confirmations could likely prevent all of the above.

The program on the remote could be trivially implemented in C (or any other language).

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231902/originate-edit-of-remote-file-using-emacs-tramp-from-ssh-session has a fairly simple accepted answer which amounts to

```
(setq server-use-tcp t)
(setq server-host "name_of_local_machine")
(server-start)
;; Maybe also muck with `server-auth-dir`
```

and then use

```
emacsclient -f ~/.emacs.d/server/server /`hostname`:/path/to/local/file
```

There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546722/using-emacs-server-and-emacsclient-on-other-machines-as-other-users which is more complex but where the answers also (roughly) touch similar bases.

Answer (score 0):

Might require a bit of tweaking, but here's the idea:

```
EDITOR="ssh artagnon@luneth \"emacsclient -n /`hostname`:$1\""
```

Comment: Do you mean ssh'ing back from the remote server to the client where Emacs is running? That's often not possible.

Comment: Well, if you can't reach the client where Emacs is running, it's impossible to do anything.

Comment: You can ask ssh, via it's ~/.ssh/config to always forward the local ssh listener to a port on the remote machine.  You'd probably want to forward your ssh-agent as well, though opinions vary as to how secure that is.   This will let you can get back by doing EDITOR="ssh $user@localhost:1234 ..."

Comment: Another option perhaps would be writing a small wrapper to call edit-server.el

Answer (score 0):

Harold Abnabit came up with this approach<sup>1</sup>:

http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/06/25/emacsclient-and-tramp/

<sup>1</sup> based on an earlier article by Ryan Barrett (to which he links).

FWIW there's also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5154224/324105 in which Petri Lehtinen came up with https://gist.github.com/akheron/850795. I imagine the more complex solutions are better, but a very simple approach might still be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Really surprised no one has mentioned `sshfs` yet. This is what I usually do when I go remote:

```
1) multi-term; sshfs user@host:/dir/i/want/ /mnt/point/on/my/machine
2) open whatever I want to edit in my local emacs
3) get-term; ssh user@host to launch executables etc
```

While `multi-term` doesn't sync the local working dir with the remote dir, it beats all the other solutions I've tried by a long shot. Although dir tracking would be a welcome feature for sure.