# Automatically update default-directory when PWD changes in shell-mode and term-mode

Tags: term, ansi-term, shell-mode

Are there any options or packages which cause `default-directory` to be updated if the working directory changes in `shell-mode` and `term-mode`? I.e. when using `cd`, but the solution would have to be more robust than just look for this particular command and maybe a few others - it should actually check the value of `$PWD` after every command, I would think.

More importantly though it should also work when connecting to a remote machine from inside a `shell-mode` or `term-mode` buffer which was first created with `default-directory` being a local directory. That's actually the feature I really need: being able to tell programmatically whether the commands I type into such terminals are run on a remote machine. I would like to get that information in form of a properly set `default-directory` and figure if there is a way to get that, then the tool doing this would also work locally as described above.

Comment: Have you looked into `dirtrack-mode`? It has a hook that may do what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the first part of your question can be done with `dirtrack-mode`.  First, you set your shell prompt to include the present working directory.  Next, you set `dirtrack-list` to a regex that tells `dirtrack-mode` how to extract it.  Example: I set `PS1` in Bash to be this:

```
export PS1="[\h:\w] $ "
```

and in Emacs I set `dirtrack-list` and turn on `dirtrack-mode`:

```
(set-variable 'dirtrack-list '("^.*[^ ]+:\\(.*\\)]" 1 nil))
(dirtrack-mode 1)
```

(Taken from [this great blog post](https://snarfed.org/why_i_run_shells_inside_emacs).)

After that, I'm able to change directories at will, and `default-directory` changes as I go.  This also works if, in a shell, I SSH to a remote machine where I've set the prompt the same way -- `cd /etc/apache2`, on the remote machine, changes `default-directory` to `/etc/apache2`.  Note, however, that this is *local* -- in the case of the remote machine, `default-directory` will still be set to `/etc/apache2` on the *local* machine.

If I understand the second part of your question, you want `default-directory` to be set to something like `remote-machine:/etc/apache2` when SSHing to another machine.  When using  [ssh-el](https://github.com/ieure/ssh-el), you can run `ssh-directory-tracking-mode` to make this work.  For example, if I run `M-x ssh`, cd to  `/etc/apache2`, then run `C-x C-f`, the prompt I see is:

```
Find Files or Url: /scp:aardvark@remote-machine:/etc/apache2
```

You can run 'M-x ssh-directory-tracking-mode` by hand, but it's more convenient to set it as a hook for ssh-mode:

```
(setq ssh-mode-hook 'ssh-directory-tracking-mode)
```

More information:

- [Directory Tracking, Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Tracking.html)
- [A great blog post](https://snarfed.org/why_i_run_shells_inside_emacs) about running shells in Emacs
- The [ssh-el](https://github.com/ieure/ssh-el) Github repo; it's also available on [MELPA](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html).  (I had no idea it wasn't part of Emacs core...)
- [EmacsWiki page on tracking shell directories by prompt](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellDirtrackByPrompt)
- [StackExchange explanation of dirtrack-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812638/emacs-i-need-and-explanation-on-dirtrack-list-variable)

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! I am actually interested in this because a package I have written has grown features which will make this desirable. It's `with-editor` which will be used by the next release of Magit. Magit itself does not use `with-editor`'s `shell-mode`/`term-mode`-support, so I probably won't integrate this before the release. But the information you provided will make it much easier to do so, once I am done with the Magit release and can again focus on other things.

Comment: Here's how to get started with `with-editor` outside of Magit: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27/how-can-i-use-my-local-emacs-client-as-the-editor-for-remote-machines-i-access. And the Magit issue which lead me to ask this question: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1638.